# Make WPF Application Fullscreen (Cover startmenu)

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to make my WPF application fullscreen. Right now the start menu prevents it from covering everything and shifts my application up. This is what I have for my MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="HTA.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    Width="1024" Height="768">
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You're probably missing the `WindowState="Maximized"`, try the following:

```
<Window x:Class="HTA.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<Window x:Class="HTA.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    Width="1024" Height="768"
    WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
```

Window state to Maximized and window style to None

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it at run time as follows :

- Assign name to the window (x:Name = "HomePage")
- In constructor just set WindowState property to Maximized as follows

> HomePage.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

Comment: Should not use the codebehind for properties which can be set in xaml.

Comment: @PetervanKekem This is pretty useful when the window is not maximized by default but rather gets maximized when user wants it to be by clicking a button, etc.

Comment: True, but in the answer it is set in the constructor. (When using the MVVM pattern, you should use the ViewModel class for this, and bind the WindowState to the property)

Answer (score 3):

```
window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
window.Left = 0;
window.Top = 0;
window.Width = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth;
window.Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
window.Topmost = true;
```

Works with multiple screens

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing it **by code** the trick is to call

```
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
```

first and then

```
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

to get it to display over the Taskbar.

Comment: This is thre trick when toggeling between full screen and non full screen in code

Answer (score 1):

If you want user to change between `WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow` and `WindowStyle.None` at **runtime** you can bring this at code behind:
Make application fullscreen:

```
RootWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
RootWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
RootWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
RootWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
RootWindow.Topmost = true;
RootWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Return to single border style:

```
RootWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
RootWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
RootWindow.Topmost = false;
```

Note that without `RootWindow.Visibility` property your window will not cover start menu, however you can skip this step if you making application fullscreen once at startup.