# How can I make a WPF window full screen (without covering the start menu) and undruggable (basically locked)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fullscreen

So I'm trying to make my WPF window full screen (to match the computer's resolution) without covering the Windows start menu. Also, I want to make the window locked so it won't be possible to drag it around or move it from it's launching state. Thanks for the help <3

Comment: To get started: play with the Window attributes WindowStyle="None" Height="your resolution-taskbar height" and Width="your resolution" in your xaml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009880/how-to-make-full-screen-mode-without-covering-the-taskbar-using-wpf-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make full screen mode, without covering the taskbar using :wpf c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009880/how-to-make-full-screen-mode-without-covering-the-taskbar-using-wpf-c-sharp)

Comment: This answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604736/make-wpf-application-fullscreen-cover-startmenu